# Unit testing for function

Tags: javascript, function, unit-testing, jasmine

I’m writing a unit test for function getNextPage(). 
I set the test: expect(this.anotherService.resources).toEqual(3);
I got error: Expected undefined to equal 3 when running the test. 
I logged the anotherService.resources and it returned 3 in console. 
Not sure why it's not working.

**Test**

```
describe('Test for someController', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('someApp');
    return inject(function($injector) {
      var $controller;
      var $q = $injector.get('$q');

      this.rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
      this.state = $injector.get('$state');
      this.stateParams = {
        id: 1,
      }
      this.location = $injector.get('$location')
      this.timeout = $injector.get('$timeout')
      this.upload = $injector.get('$upload')
      this.someService = {
        getItemList: function(res) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve({
            data: {
              totalRows: 2,
              rows: 3,
            }
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        },
        pages: jasmine.createSpy(),

        memberIds: 1,
        currEng: []
      };
      this.anotherService = {
        resources: {}
      };
      this.scope = this.rootScope.$new();
      this.controller = $controller('someController', {
        '$scope': this.scope,
        '$rootScope': this.rootScope,
        '$state': this.state,
        '$stateParams': this.stateParams,
        '$location': this.location,
        '$timeout': this.timeout,
        '$upload': this.upload,
        'someService': this.someService,
      });
      this.scope.$digest();
    });
  });

  it('should be defined', function() {
    expect(this.controller).toBeDefined();
    expect(this.scope.ss).toEqual(this.someService);
  });

  it('should run the getNextPage function', function() {
    this.scope.getNextPage();
    this.scope.$digest();
    console.log(this.anotherService.resources);        // this is showing as Object {} in terminal
    expect(this.anotherService.resources).toEqual(3);
  });
```

**Code:**

```
someapp.controller('someController', resource);
resource.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location','$timeout','$upload', 'someService', 'anotherService'];
function resource($scope, $state, $stateParams,$location,$timeout, $upload, someService, anotherService) {

      $scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null && (window.FileAPI == null || FileAPI.html5 != false);

      $scope.ss = EsomeService;
      $scope.as = anotherService;
      $scope.getNextPage = getNextPage;


      function getNextPage(options){

        var o = options || {selected:1};
        var start = (o.selected-1)*10 || 0;
        someService.currPage = o.selected;

        someService.getItemList($stateParams.id,'F', start).then(function (res){
          anotherService.resources = res.data.rows;
          console.log(anotherService.resources)   // this shows LOG: 3 in terminal
          someService.numResults = res.data.totalRows;
          someService.pageNumbers = someService.pages(res.data.totalRows,10);
        })
      }
});
```

Comment: You need to wait for the promise.

Comment: Why are you using a promise at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `this.anotherService.resources` is still `{}` in your test because the code in the following `then` callback is executed *after* your test runs, asynchronously:

```
someService.getItemList($stateParams.id,'F', start).then(function (res){
    anotherService.resources = res.data.rows;
    console.log(anotherService.resources)
    someService.numResults = res.data.totalRows;
    someService.pageNumbers = someService.pages(res.data.totalRows,10);
})
```

Although in `getItemList` you resolve the promise synchronously

```
getItemList: function(res) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve({
        data: {
            totalRows: 2,
            rows: 3,
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

... it actually does not call the `then` function on the promise immediately when you call `deferred.resolve`. When you think of it, that would not make sense either, because the promise must first be returned to the caller before the caller can attach the `then` call back to it. Instead it calls the `then` callback asynchronously, i.e. after all currently executing code finishes with an empty call stack. This includes your test code! As stated in the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api):

> `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)` – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, `then` calls one of the success or error callbacks ***asynchronously*** as soon as the result is available.

and also in the [testing example in the same documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing):

> ```
> // Simulate resolving of promise
> deferred.resolve(123);
> // Note that the 'then' function does not get called synchronously.
> // This is because we want the promise API to always be async, whether or not
> // it got called synchronously or asynchronously.
> ```

#### How to test asynchronous code

First, you could let `getNextPage` return a promise -- the same promise that `getItemList` returns:

```
function getNextPage(options){
    var o = options || {selected:1};
    var start = (o.selected-1)*10 || 0;
    someService.currPage = o.selected;
    // store the promise in a variable
    var prom = someService.getItemList($stateParams.id,'F', start);
    prom.then(function (res){
        anotherService.resources = res.data.rows;
        console.log(anotherService.resources)   // this shows LOG: 3 in terminal
        someService.numResults = res.data.totalRows;
        someService.pageNumbers = someService.pages(res.data.totalRows,10);
    });
    return prom; // return that promise
}
```

And then you can use `then` on `getNextPage()`, which will execute in sequence with any other `then` callbacks attached to it, so after the `then` callback in the above piece of code.

Jasmine's [`done`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) can then be used to tell Jasmine the test is asynchronous and when it has completed:

```
// The presence of the `done` parameter indicates to Jasmine that 
// the test is asynchronous 
it('should run the getNextPage function', function(done) { 
    this.scope.getNextPage().then(function () {
        this.scope.$digest();
        console.log(this.anotherService.resources);
        expect(this.anotherService.resources).toEqual(3);
        done(); // indicate to Jasmine that the asynchronous test has completed
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried using .bing(this) it returned me with a different error. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.scope.getNextPage')

Comment: That might indicate that  `this` is already not what you think it is when arriving at the `it` call. Can you please explain what you want `this` to be, and maybe provide the complete context in which `it` is called?

Comment: I think you were right, I tried console.log(this.anotherService.resources) and its returning me an object instead. 
I’ve set the data in someService to be totalRows: 2 and rows: 3. I’m expecting rows to pass through the promise and return 3 for anotherService.resource.

Comment: Can you provide more code in your question so I can see where you have placed the tests? The result of `console.log(this............)` depends on where you put it. Every line of code with `this` is context sensitive, so in your question please make sure the code-context is clear, otherwise we're looking in the dark.

Comment: here is a more complete version of the code, hopefully things would make more sense. Thanks!

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer. Please have a look.